# get most recent record from json having epoch time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am creating app using angularjs.I have json like:

```
{
    "dps": {
      "1455719820": 0,
      "1455720150": 0,
      "1455720480": 0,
      "1455720810": 0,
      "1455721140": 0,
      "1455721470": 0,
      "1455721800": 0,
      "1455722130": 0
    }
  }
```

I want to get the value of most recent time from json. I don't know how can i do this.

Comment: you'll need these three tools - `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON string ... `Object.keys` to get an array of keys ... `Array#sort` to sort these keys ... then the realisation that all your keys have the same value i.e. `0`, so you've wasted your time on code :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most compatible way and easiest to read in my opinion:

1. Use the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
2. [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) them if necessary (in your example not necessary)
3. access the value (in your example always 0) using pop or arr[arr.length-1]

```js
var o = {
    "dps": {
      "1455719820": 10,
      "1455720150": 90,
      "1455720480": 110,
      "1455720810": 560,
      "1455721140": 670,
      "1455721470": 120,
      "1455721800": 9,
      "1455722130": 130
    }
  }

// just sorting
var arr = Object.keys(o.dps).sort(); // your keys were actually already sorted
console.log(arr);

// To get the latest value; 
var newest = arr.pop();
var val = o.dps[newest];
console.log(newest,val)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var biggest=0;
 var obj = {
    "dps": {
      "1455719820": 0,
      "1455720150": 0,
      "1455720480": 0,
      "1455720810": 0,
      "1455721140": 0,
      "1455721470": 0,
      "1455721800": 0,
      "1455722130": 0
    }
  }
for(key in obj.dps){
    if(biggest<key){
          biggest = key;
    }
}

// biggest will now have the biggest timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which performs a single loop, without sorting the keys in advance.

```js
var data = { "dps": { "1455719820": 0, "1455720150": 0, "1455720480": 0, "1455720810": 0, "1455721140": 0, "1455721470": 0, "1455721800": 0, "1455722130": 42 } },
    result = data.dps[Object.keys(data.dps).reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r < a ? a : r;
    }, 0)];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var o = {
  "dps": {
    "1455719820": 0,
    "1455720150": 0,
    "1455720480": 0,
    "1455720810": 0,
    "1455721140": 0,
    "1455721470": 0,
    "1455721800": 0,
    "1455722130": 0
  }
}

var max = Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(o.dps));

console.log(max);
```